# keyboard control PySide

Tags: python, pyside

I want to add extra shortcut below codes for example such as + f4  what should I do?

```
enter code here
    import sys
    import time,pyautogui
    from PySide.QtGui import QApplication
    from PySide.QtCore import QUrl
    from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebView

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    b = QWebView()
    b.load(QUrl('http://bc.vc/EjwKZx'))

    b.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create shortcuts with the [`QShortcut`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qshortcut.html) class.  If you want them to be application wide, make sure to use the [`Qt.ApplicationShortcut`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#ShortcutContext-enum) context.